# How do I merge two table?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I do have two table each with 50000 data. both tables id starts from 1 - 50000 so when I try to insert to table_1 from table_2 by using

```
INSERT IGNORE
  INTO table_1 
SELECT *
  FROM table_2
```

it completely rewrites the existing one. I dont want to rewrite it but add as new so it will totallying 100k. but may say 5 to 10 duplicates in index column so duplicate check on index too. how can I do this??

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP or another favorite language, this will be about 10-20 lines of code...

Comment: This doesn't answer his question, so should be in the comment section. Also you have no idea of his setup so php my not be relevant to him e.g. could be Python application etc.

Comment: That´s why I wrote "or another favorite language"

Answer (score 0):

If table_1 and table_2 need to have different keys first of all for a successfull merge to occur

table_1 keys will have to start from 1-50000 and table_2 key value will have to start from 50001-100000

For duplication you can deal using the on update functionality in mysql

```
INSERT INTO table_1
    SELECT * FROM table_2
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE table_1.val=table_1.val
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is an primary key column you have to exclude it from the insert if there is duplicates there.

One solution is to insert with a select that removes duplicate values.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_1 (f1, f2, f3)
SELECT f1, f2, f2 FROM table_2 WHERE table_2.index NOT IN (SELECT index FROM table_1)
```

OBS, this is not very efficient on a slow database server and could be written better with more information on the tables.